# Python lxml Cleaner module was not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, python, regex, web-scraping, lxml

In my webscraper some of the content is coming with advertisements and some java script functions in it. Like the below;

**(function() {                                 var infAds = document.createElement('script');                                 infAds.async = true;                                 infAds.type = 'text/javascript';                                 var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;                                 infAds.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//d.infeed.id/widget-50716010/loader/all/';                                 var node = document.getElementById('cont-50716010-all');                                 node.parentNode.insertBefore(infAds, node);                             })();**

I have used lxml.html.clean.Cleaner to remove the scripts and styles from the content. But it is not all removing what i expected. I tried like the below;

```
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner
cleaner = Cleaner()
cleaner.javascript = True
cleaner.scripts = True
content = "Page content"
clean_content = cleaner.clean_html(content)
print(clean_content)
```

But if i use
__clean_content = lxml.html.toString(cleaner.clean_html(content))
__
i am getting the below type error;
**TypeError: Type 'str' cannot be serialized.**

Using regex also i have tried, it wasn't worked out too. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciable!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `clean_html()` returns a string; why are you calling `toString` on a string?

Comment: clean_html() returns a string. yes, you're right. But i am getting some html tags in the result like <p> and <div> though i mentioned like the cleaner.remove_tags = ['p','div']